# Why is the modelstate invalid in my razor page when I use a class type as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

This is my first go at using Razor Pages in ASP.Net Core 2.2 and I'm utilizing a page filter to check the `ModelState.IsValid` which is returning false on `GET` requests when I use a type in an `OnGet()` method parameter which is causing the page to fail. If I change the signature of the method to use a primitive type, the model state is valid.

An example is  as follows:

`ModelState.IsValid` is *false* for the below code, which works fine in a controller action in ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string IsValid { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(Query query)
    {
        // FALSE
        IsValid = ModelState.IsValid.ToString();
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public int? Page { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But it is *true* for the below:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string IsValid { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int? query)
    {
        // TRUE
        IsValid = ModelState.IsValid.ToString();
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because by default the get is unable to bind to the complex objects. Model binding attributes would need to be applied. Where is the data coming from to bind that object?

Comment: @Nkosi I have written MVC apps which automagically bind the querystring values to the complex type with no issues and no modelbinding attributes.

Comment: It is different for razor pages. You have to explicitly tell it where you want to bind from. ie:`public void OnGet([FromQuery]Query query)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Razor Pages, by default, bind properties only with non-GET verbs.

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/)

Because by default, the GET is unable to bind to complex objects. Model binding attributes would need to be applied.

You have to explicitly tell it where you want to bind from.

For example

```
public void OnGet([FromQuery]Query query) {
   IsValid = ModelState.IsValid.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of applying the `Query` type as a parameter to the `OnGet` method, you can add it as a PageModel property instead, decorated with the `BindProperty` attribute:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string IsValid { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public Query query { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public class Query
    {
        public int? Page { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When the `BindProperty` attribute is used, you have to opt in to binding taking place in `GET` request (hence `SupportsGet=true`), but when you work with PageModel properties, you don't need to tell model binding where to get the values from. It will automatically search query strings, the request body, route data etc.

More info: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-data-from-get-requests

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on complex types: "Error CS0592 Attribute 'BindProperty' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations."

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to apply it to a class, rather than a property. You can't use `BindProperty` on the PageModel, for example.